# Insert Python Dictionary as a column in Cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra, cql

I want to insert a python dictionary in the formal below to a Cassandra database column.

```
data= {'key1':25,'key2':10.12,'key3':[1,2,3],'key4': 'SomeText'}
```

As you can see its a mixture of various datatype elements. I am thinking about defining the column as

```
some_column=map()
```

and passing the dictionary during insert operation. This dictionary will be inserted as a group insert along with 100 other variables. Is there any better or memory efficient way of doing this? I don't have access to the database yet, so i cannot execute the code above and see the status.

Comment: Do you mean Cass**a**ndra DB?

Comment: Yes, I want to add a new column to a existing Cassandra DB? Its a typo, i will fix it

Comment: Do it in smaller chunks, when using dictionary you are sacrificing space for time.

Comment: Do you think converting the data to json and finally storing as text would be a better option ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't insert multiple data types as a value into the same map - you always n[eed to declare specific types for key & value](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useMap.html) inside map.

If you really need to store heterogenous data there, you can declare the field as text, and insert into it your dictionary serialized as JSON, for example, and deserialize when you're reading.  (or you can use the blob type, and serialize/deserialize to/from byte array as pickle - depending on your requirements).